# How to reverse individual lines and words in Python3 specifically working on each paragraph in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, reverse

Basically, I have a text file: -

> Plants are mainly multi-cellular. Green plants obtain most of their
>   energy from sunlight via photosynthesis. There are about 320,000
>   species of plants. Some 260–290 thousand, produce seeds. Green plants
>   produce oxygen.
>
> Green plants occupy a significant amount of land today. We should
>   conserve this greenery around us.

I wanted the output to be:-

> oxygen. produce plants Green seeds. produce thousand, 260-290 Some
>   plants. of species 320,000 about are There photosynthesis. via
>   sunlight from energy their of most obtain plants Green multi-cellular.
>   mainly are Plants
>
> us. around greenery this conserve should we today. land of amount
>   significant a occupy plants Green.

I used `split()` and then used `.join()` to combine the file, but it ended up reversing the whole thing and not paragraph-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Change** `open("testp.txt")` to `open("[path to your file]")`

```py
import re

text = open("testp.txt").read()
rtext = ""

for p in re.split("\n", text):
    for w in reversed(re.split(" ", p)):
        rtext += w + " "
    rtext = rtext[:-1] + "\n"
rtext = rtext[:-1]

print(rtext)
```

**Update:** this one is so simple:

```py
import re

with open("testp.txt") as f:
    print("\n".join(
        " ".join(reversed(re.split(" ", p))) for p in re.split("\n", f.read())
    ))
```

**Update:** code without using regex:

```py
with open("testp.txt") as f:
    print("\n".join(
        " ".join(reversed(p.split())) for p in f.read().splitlines()
    ))
```

> **Note that** you can use `.split("\n")` instead of `.splitlines()`

The result for all versions is:

> ### Input:
>
> Plants are mainly multi-cellular. Green plants obtain most of their energy from sunlight via photosynthesis. There are about 320,000 species of plants. Some 260–290 thousand, produce seeds. Green plants produce oxygen.
>
> Green plants occupy a significant amount of land today. We should conserve this greenery around us.
>
> ### Output:
>
> oxygen. produce plants Green seeds. produce thousand, 260-290 Some plants. of species 320,000 about are There photosynthesis. via sunlight from energy their of most obtain plants Green multi-cellular. mainly are Plants
>
> us. around greenery this conserve should we today. land of amount significant a occupy plants Green

Comment: Thank you @A! But while writing back to the output file I am getting an error. 
`with open("input.txt") as f:
    read_data = f.read().splitlines()


with open("output.txt") as fout:
    for p in read_data:
        words = p.split()
    fout.write(' '.join(words[::-1]))
fout.close()`

Comment: @j_robot maybe you don't have permission to write into `fout`; change `open("output.txt")` to `open("output.txt", "w")`.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file and use `splitlines()` to separate paragraphs. Then iterate the paragraphs, reversing the words.

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    read_data = f.read().splitlines()

    for p in read_data:
        words = p.split()
        print(' '.join(reversed(words)))
```

To read and write to file you can do this:

```
with open("input.txt", 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.read().splitlines()

with open("output.txt", 'w') as fout:
    for p in read_data:
        words = p.split()
        fout.write(' '.join(reversed(words)))
        fout.write('\n')
```

Comment: How to write this back to a new file? 
`with open("input.txt") as f:
    read_data = f.read().splitlines()


with open("output.txt") as fout:
    for p in read_data:
        words = p.split()
    fout.write(' '.join(words[::-1]))
fout.close()`

This is giving an error.

Comment: @j_robot No need to to do `fout.close` because you are using a context manager (`with open('..')`). The file will be closed automatically when you leave the `with` context.

Comment: so then how should I write to an `output.txt` from your code then?

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks you!